# Creating more permanent crontab files

Tags: bash, unix, cron

I just recently asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359367/running-a-bash-program-every-day-at-the-same-time

The solution of using crontab -e to create a job worked very well and my script worked fine.
However, I found that once I exited the terminal, that job was deleted. How can I create a job mediated by cron that will work every day at the same regardless of if I exit the terminal or even turn off my computer (assuming my computer is turned back when the cron job is scheduled to execute)

Comment: What kind of system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cron is permanent. So the accepted answer given in the linked question would run the script at 7 AM everyday. It has nothing to do with if you are logged in or not.

Comment: Agree, cron shouldn't go away when you log out.

Comment: I think I saved the file as a temporary file, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363321/saving-crontab-files

Comment: @Phil, If you do crontab -e and save (without giving another name while saving), it would save to correct location.